Apply calculator operations to Strings
I've got the following Java (8) code, think of it as a kind of calculator that reads numbers from a file and then applies an operation (with another number, both supplied by the user) to each one:
String originalstring = "-1000"; //read from the file
char symbol = '+'; //depends on user input
long numberone = 1000; //-"-
long numbertwo = 2000; //-"-
String newstring = "";

if(originalstring.charAt(0)=='-') {
    switch(symbol) {
    case '=':
        newstring = numberone + "";
        break;
    case '+':
        newstring = (Long.parseLong(originalstring) + numberone) + "";
        break;
    case '-':
        newstring = (Long.parseLong(originalstring) - numberone) + "";
        break;
    }
} else {
    switch(symbol) {
    case '=':
        newstring = numbertwo + "";
        break;
    case '+':
        newstring = (Long.parseLong(originalstring) + numbertwo) + "";
        break;
    case '-':
        newstring = (Long.parseLong(originalstring) - numbertwo) + "";
        break;
    }
}

An alternative would be to use switch on the outside and use the if statement in every case (possibly with the ternary operator to shorten it a little bit). Both versions would be approximately the same length and to me it also doesn't look like one version would be faster than the other, so:
What's the best practice for what should be inside and what should be outside if there aren't any loops (like in this question)? Is there even a best practice or does it simply come down to personal preference in cases like this where performance seems to be the same?
I'm aware that there's a third version: Keep the if/else, move the switch to its own function and either pass numberone or numbertwo as parameter but there's more code after this that works with newstring, so it would be harder to see how it's created and it would also be overkill for just 11 lines of code that aren't used again anywhere else.

To help reviewers give you better answers, we need to know what the code is intended to achieve.  Please add sufficient context to your question to describe the purpose of the code. We want to know why much more than how. The more you tell us about what your code is for, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you.  Also, [edit] the title to simply summarise the task, rather than your concerns about the code.

@TobySpeight I added a description and fixed the title.

The title still talks too much about your implementation choices.  The site standard is for the title to simply summarise the task accomplished by the code. Please see How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions for guidance on writing good question titles.

@TobySpeight What would you suggest? My code works, I don't need help to make it work ("apply calculator operations to strings") but to optimize it and make it use existing best practices. That's what I'm interested in and that's what the title describes imo. Answers in this question say that questions like that should be asked here on Code Review.

Yes, "apply calculator operations to strings" sounds like a good description of what this code is doing.  I would recommend that as a title.

@TobySpeight Okay, changed it. The two answers helped get rid of the duplicate code but how/where can I get an answer to the "best practice" question for if/switch?

We don't do general "best practice" questions here, only reviews of specific code.  I don't think there's a StackExchange site that's a strong match for that, but you might investigate [swe.se] - read their help centre and any highly-voted questions of a similar vein to find out what's acceptable there.

there is an option which eliminates the need for switch: use of enum. java enum has the capabilities of any java class, including instance variables and methods. the solution I propose has the following design:

create an enum with values per the symbols that perform calculation: EQUAL, PLUS, MINUS.
every enum value will have a property (instance variable) with the relevant character value. for example, EQUALS will have property '=' . a static method of the enum will receive the user input, iterate over the enum values() and return Optional populated if match was found
every enum value will implement a method that does the calculation. the method will choose between numberone and numbertwo, perform the math calculation and return string value.
with the all the above imlpemented, it is straightforward to do calculation from user input

this solution will likely add more lines of code compared to solution using switch (depends on formatting...) however, it is build for robustness: adding a new symbol requires only adding a new enum value with implementation of calculate.
here is the enum class, with symbol property, calculate method and static method to get value from user input
public enum Symbol {

    EQUAL('=') {
        @Override
        public String calculate(String originalstring, long numberone, long numbertwo) {
            // return chosen number as is
            return String.valueOf(getNumberToCalcaulte(originalstring, numberone, numbertwo));
        }
    },

    PLUS('+') {
        @Override
        public String calculate(String originalstring, long numberone, long numbertwo) {
            // return original + chosen number
            return String.valueOf(
                Long.parseLong(originalstring) +
                getNumberToCalcaulte(originalstring, numberone, numbertwo)
            );
        }
    },

    MINUS('-') {
        @Override
        public String calculate(String originalstring, long numberone, long numbertwo) {
            // return original - chosen number
            return String.valueOf(
                Long.parseLong(originalstring) -
                getNumberToCalcaulte(originalstring, numberone, numbertwo)
            );
        }
    };

    // property char symbol
    private char symbol;

    /**
     * iterate over enum values, 
     * return first value with property matching user input, otherwise empty
     */
    public static Optional<Symbol> getSymbol(char userInput) {
        // values() produces an array, thus need for Arrays to stream
        return Arrays.stream(values())
            .filter(val -> val.symbol == userInput)
            .findFirst();
    }

    Symbol(char symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }

    /**
     * signature of calculate method, implemented in each value
     */
    public abstract String calculate(String originalstring, long numberone, long numbertwo);

    /**
     * choose number to calculate based on first char of original 
     */
    private static long getNumberToCalcaulte(String originalstring, long numberone, long numbertwo) {
        return (originalstring.charAt(0) == '-') ? numberone : numbertwo;
    }
}

usage of the enum to do the calculation
    String originalstring = "-1000"; //read from a file
    char symbol = '+'; //depends on user input
    long numberone = 1000; //-"-
    long numbertwo = 2000; //-"-

    String newstring = Symbol.getSymbol(symbol)
        .map(matchedSymbol -> matchedSymbol.calculate(originalstring, numberone, numbertwo))
        .orElse("");


That's an interesting solution! Is this Java 8 code (asking because of the ->)? How efficient is it compared to switch? There's currently no need for extra symbols because only whole numbers are used for calculations (no * or /) but you're right, it would be easy to add more.

this code is compatible with java 8. the -> is used in collection stream

How it would be done here
First the current case.
The use case looks like an interactive calculator, some state machine.
That would look best (in the latest switch syntax) like:
long number = originalstring.startsWith("-") ? numberone : numbertwo;

String message = "";   
long register = Long.parseLong(originalstring);
switch (symbol) {
    case '=' ->
        register = number;
    case '+' ->
        register += number;
    case '-' ->
        register -= number;
    default ->
        message = "";
}
if (message.isEmpty()) {
    message = Long.toString(register);
}

The precise question
Concerning nesting one within another of if and switch. If the switches are longer and vary, it probably is more readable to understand one if-branch when the switch-branch is inside: shorter text, following a consistent line across the cases.
if
    switch
    case ...
    case ...
    case ...
    case ...
    case ...
else
    switch
    case ...
    case ...

than:
switch
case ...
    if ...
    else ...
case ...
    if ...
    else ...
case ...
    if ...
    else ...
case ...
    if ...
    else ...
case ...
    if ...
    else ...

The context of processing many cases
The last remark. So many cross-concerns, matrix like processing, would benefit from a declarative solution. Where you have a tabular structure of data.
You can then iterate over the defined data, and even log how you arrived to the solution. This makes for traceable and verifiable results. If the result are 2x8 PDF reports, you can use metadata in the PDF indicating the followed data branch.

Yes, that's what it is, it reads a text file and applies similar calculator operations (input by the user) to every number/String (the exceptions don't matter for this question). Why do you use a default case if the resulting String is already initialized as "" and what Java version is the -> from? Thanks for also replying to my "best practice" question! Basically: Use the shortest version that looks like it has the least repetitions? Sorry, I don't think I understand. There are only 3 cases atm and the whole number results (so no * or /) are passed back to the calling function.

I added the default to show mixed long register/String message usage. (I wanted to do away with long/String back and forth conversions. Admitted I am biased towards if(switch). Switch statement and even switch expressions are present since Java 14; a no-brainer.

I see. I'm currently using Java 8, so a little bit off from Java 14 but it should still work the same way.

Java 8 is the minimum. A more recent java (say ~21) is really worthwile. Especially code quality if ()x instanceof A a) { a ... } and many more.

I'm also using Java 11 for some things but it's always a question of compatibility and there's also the whole Oracle licensing thing. But yes, I'm aware I'm going to have to update sooner rather than later.

Your current implementation has duplicate logic, which is bad because it means you'll need to change it in two places if it ever needs to change.
First determine the value of numberValue:
long numberValue = originalstring.charAt(0)=='-'
    ? 1000
    : 2000;

and then use one switch:
switch(symbol) {
    case '=':
        newstring = numberValue + "";
        break;
    case '+':
        newstring = (Long.parseLong(originalstring) + numberValue) + "";
        break;
    case '-':
        newstring = (Long.parseLong(originalstring) - numberValue) + "";
        break;
    }


Yes, that's one thing I didn't like about this either but your and user287991's solution is great (not sure why I didn't think about that)! It does add the extra numberValue but I didn't say in the question that this code is part of a loop, so that's fine (I'm just going to declare it outside). I'm still curious however: Would there be a preferred order of if and switch if it wasn't that easy to just do the check beforehand for some reason?

@Neph Please do not post just a part of the code when the whole context is important. CR can handle significant code blocks, you don't need to reduce your code. If the loop is important, post the loop. However, you'll need to post a new question for that and not alter this one.
